# Python: json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)

Tags: python, python-3.x, api

Requirement: Pull API data with a date range of every 10 mins, so that I don't get a bulk of data and cause CPU/RAM issue and have better performance

Example : Range of dates is start_date = '2022-06-05' and end_date ='2022-06-06'

So When I loop data from API, it should first start_date and end_date as below

```
start_dt:2022-06-05 00:00:00 end_dt:2022-06-05 00:10:00 
start_dt:2022-06-05 00:10:00 end_dt:2022-06-05 00:20:00 
start_dt:2022-06-05 00:20:00 end_dt:2022-06-05 00:30:00 
start_dt:2022-06-05 00:30:00 end_dt:2022-06-05 00:40:00 



try:
        batch_start_dt = datetime.strptime(date_run, '%Y-%m-%d')
        batch_end_dt =  datetime.strptime(date_run, '%Y-%m-%d')  + timedelta(days=1)
        timedelta_index = pd.date_range(start=batch_start_dt, end=batch_end_dt, freq='10T').to_series()
        for index, value in timedelta_index.iteritems():
            start_dt  = index.to_pydatetime()
            end_dt    = start_dt + pd.Timedelta("20T")

            start_dt2 = start_dt.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
            end_dt2   = end_dt.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
            request_url = ("https://%s:443/api/ChangeList?fromDate=%sZ&endDate=%sZ&timeBufferInSecs=1200&firstLevelFieldsOnly=true"
                        % (api_url,start_dt2.replace(" ", "T"),end_dt2.replace(" ", "T")))
            client.request("GET", request_url, headers=headers)
            response = client.getresponse()
            data = response.read().decode("UTF-8").strip("")
            json_results = json.loads(data)
            json_arr.extend(json_results)
            start_dt += delta
            end_dt += delta
```

Error:=

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/airflow/dags/date_api.py", line 165, in execute
  File "/opt/airflow/dags/date_api.py", line 129, in call_api
    json_results = json.loads(data)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/json/__init__.py", line 348, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/json/decoder.py", line 337, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/json/decoder.py", line 355, in raw_decode
    raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
```

Comment: Just search for the error message, it comes up every week or so and today once more.

Comment: When tried as date range it works fine but timestamp its failing

Comment: All of this is not the cause of your problem. Begin by understanding what causes the exception that is raised!

Answer (score 1):

You could use pandas.DateRange here:

```
import pandas as pd

idx = pd.DateRange(start_date, end_date, freq='10M') # Generate 10-minute intervals

for t in idx:
    # ...
```

Comment: How do i get `start_date` and `end_date` with timestamp

Comment: Either pass in a str or datetime. So you can replace the `start_date` with `start_dt` as defined in your code

Comment: Can you please check updated , I am not able to figure out of end_dt to pass into api with every range incremental